# minimum number of comparisons needed

Tags: algorithm, comparison

what is the minimum number of comparisons needed to find the largest element from 4 distinct elements? I know for 5 distinct numbers it is 6, floor(5/2) * 3; this is from clrs book. but I know there is no one general formula for finding this, or is there?

**edit clarification**

these 4 elements could be in any different order(for all permutations of these 4 elements) im not interested in a counting technique to keep track of the largest element as you traverse the elements, but comparisons like > or <.

Answer (score 6):

for 4 elements the min. number of comparisons is 3.

In general, to find largest of `N` elements you need `N-1` comparisons. This gives you 4 for 5 numbers, not 6.

**Proof:**

1. there is always a solution with `N-1` comparisons: just compare first two and then select the larger and compare with next one, select the larger and compare with next one etc....
2. there cannot be shorter solution because this solution would not compare all the elements.

QED.

Comment: the second part of the proof is quite sloppy. check my answer, based on that it's easy to proof that part.

Comment: Karoly, you have not proved anything in your current answer, you just state the theorem to be proven. What I showed is typical and clear proof in used in informatics.

Comment: actually you need 6 for 5 elements using a decision tree, but my intuition was like you first

Comment: @Tomas: no it isn't. why wouldn't that compare all the elements? where is the proof of that? (and yes, my answer is not complete, but if you look closer you'll see I didn't put the word *proof* there)

Comment: @David, "you need 6 for 5 elements **using a decision tree**"... if this is true, then this means that decision tree is not a good tool for this task. 4 comparisons are enough, see point 1 of my proof.

Comment: @Tomas Im trying to find for all the permutations

Comment: @David, your question states you are trying to find the **largest element**. Permutation is something completely different. We answered the question as it was asked and cannot do any better :-)

Comment: @Tomas yes I said minimum number of comparisons needed to find the largest element from 4 distinct elements. these 4 elements could be in any different order. probably you used a counting technique, to keep track of the largest element as you traverse the elements, but I am interested in comparisons. sorry for the confusion

Comment: I don't get what this discussion is about. Probably would be worth restating the original question.

Comment: Thanks! But I don't get what you find wrong in Tomas' answer. More precisely, I don't understand what you meant by "Im trying to find for all the permutations". Tomas' algorithm handles any permutation (i.e. any unsorted array).
Also, what page of the clrs book says that for 5 distinct numbers it is 6, floor(5/2) * 3?

Comment: Thanks Franck. Yes @David, my solution of course handles all permutations and uses `N-1` **comparisons**. Sorry, I don't know how to explain this further.

Comment: Thomas i'm afraid your proof isn't true in general. If one is using ints with a fixed limit due to overflow, and one encounters the maximum allowable int, then one knows that is the max without having to look through the rest of the list.

Comment: Tomas gave a mathematical proof. A nice world without overflow and such :)

Answer (score 5):

I know it does not answer the original question, but I enjoyed reading this not-so-intuitive post on [the minimum number of comparisons needed to find the smallest AND the largest number from an unsorted array](http://standardwisdom.com/softwarejournal/2011/02/min-max-array/) (with proof).

Answer (score 3):

Think of it as a competition. By comparing two elements you have a looser and a winner.

So if you have `n` elements and need 1 final winner you need `n-1` comparisons to rule out the other ones.

Comment: please see the above comments

Answer (score -1):

for elements a,b,c,d

if a>b+c+d, then it only required one comparison to know that a is the biggest.

You do have to get lucky though.